# Center a div and give color to space of one side

Tags: html, css

I want a centered div and I wand left side of it to be filled with color (as in my examples).

I have 2 solutions (not using flexbox) here and they both feel like hacks.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
}

.center-part {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: inherit;
    background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.8);
    position: relative;
}

.blue-big {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 9999px;
    height: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    right: 500px;
}

.equal-side {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" style="top: 0px">
    <div class="center-part">
        <div class="blue-big">
        
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="header" style="top: 70px; display: table;">
    <div class="equal-side" style="background-color: blue">
    </div>
    <div class="center-part" style="display: table-cell;">
    </div>
    <div class="equal-side">
    </div>
</div>
```

Top one uses large div and positioning, but second one uses "display: table"

I'd like to know if any of them is <s>good</s> ok kinda practice or should I do this someway else?

<del>Blue</del> Green DIV will not actually be full height, so putting div in background with 50% width is not an option

Comment: Can you not use flexbox? Or just don't want to?

Comment: I need to have both

Comment: Why don't use pseudo selectors to achieve blue color background

Comment: @Master.Deep what do you mean by that?

Comment: @NoOorZ24, You can achieve that by psuedo selector, as Temani has suggested

Comment: @Master.Deep but it's not much different from my top example it does pretty much the same

Comment: Considering a HTML element just for styling is seems to be hack. Although psuedo selector can be use to achieve the styling part and properties also looks pretty logical so that's not hack.

Comment: @Master.Deep I mean I understood that it's a better approach and if nothing else is suggested I'll go with it, but I was just thinking if there might be a totally different approach

Comment: @NoOorZ24 I have updated my answer, so please take a look below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more simple solution is to use linear-gradient like this:

```css
.container {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green 50%, transparent 0) 0 0/100% 40% no-repeat;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}

.container>div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40%;
  background:blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Or consider a pseudo element overflowing:

```css
.container {
  overflow:hidden;
  height: 100px;
}

.container>div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background:blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
}
.container>div:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left:-1000%;
  bottom:0;
  background:green;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my question - 50% hack is not really an option. Had taught about it as well

Comment: @NoOorZ24 updated as well ;) you can easily control the linear gradient to adjust it size

Answer (score 1):

This solution works for me https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GdeYdK?editors=1100

HTML:

```
    <div class="test-header">
  <div class="equal-side left-side">
  </div>
  <div class="center-part">
     <div class="center">
       SOME TEXT HERE
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="equal-side right-side">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .test-header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.equal-side {  
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 49%;
}

.left-side {
  background: blue;
}

.right-side {
  background: red;
}

.center-part {
  background: white;
  width: 500px;
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -250px;   /*half of center element's width*/
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
}

.center {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed;
}
```

Comment: calc has worse support than flexbox so I'd just prefer using flexbox over calc

Comment: @NoOorZ24 You can use `width: 33.3333333333%;` then. It is simple and works too.

Comment: but I don't need 3 equal parts. I need middle part to have  fixed size and to be in the middle. Only sides should adapt to viewport size

Comment: @NoOorZ24 Take a look, I have updated the answer for you

Comment: "Blue DIV will not actually be full height, so putting div in background with 50% width is not an option"

Comment: @NoOorZ24 So you want the blue div to have auto width from left side to the left border of the center green div, correct? I will try to update

Comment: Yes, I want behavior that works exactly like in my examples

Comment: @NoOorZ24 I have updated the answer, so basically you can use `min-height` for example `min-height: 10px;` . The height does not need to be fixed and can be flexible by using `min-height` for the left/right divs

Comment: I messed up blue with green, I meant green one will be not be fully filled, I'll at least give you an upvote for trying to help as I messed it up myself

Comment: @NoOorZ24 Why dont you put another 100% wide div inside the green div in the middle?

Answer (score -1):

You can use a linear gradient and need only one element - see also [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/) on this topic. They have great explanations on how to do this kind of thing.

In my original answer I forgot to include the container to center the div. I've updated to two examples - one using flexbox and one without. I'm not quite sure if you cannot use flexbox, or don't want to - so I've included both.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bar {
  height: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(
      to right, 
      red,
      red 50%,
      orange 50%,
      orange 100%
    );
}

.bar-noflexbox {
  height: 50px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 1rem 20%;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(
      to right, 
      red,
      red 50%,
      orange 50%,
      orange 100%
    );
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="bar-noflexbox"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Setting hard percentages creates the clean line - if you were to remove the percentages you get a smooth gradient from red to orange over the whole width of the element.
You can also add multiple colors by adding colors and percentages in the linear-gradient field.